# Why can't I use the mouse at all?

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-mate

This morning, on restarting my laptop (Ubuntu Mate 20.04) my mouse stopped working completely under Linux, both the physical buttons and tapping the trackpad (although the trackpad still works to scroll). For example, I can start firefox from the terminal, but not by clicking on the launch icon, and once firefox is started then I cannot use any GUI buttons or website that requires interacting with the mouse (although the application is not frozen).

I can move the cursor but often a rectangle will appear around it as if I had clicked the mouse and were dragging it around. It does not seem to be a hardware problem since rebooting from my second SSD into Windows 10 everything works OK.

How can I figure out what is happening?

---

### Edit:

The answer below worked, but only for around an hour. I have needed to do it several times since then. Is there any way to diagnose what might be causing this problem? Everything is up-to-date and all necessary drivers are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Hope this works.